# what are the jquery ui selectmenu widget minimum css and js requirements?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm about to use the jquery ui selectmenu widget and it will be the only one ui I'll use in my project. So I'd like to use the minimum js and css possible. I read the docs and took a look to the repo but I can't fully understand what to use.

What are (beside jquery itself) the minimum js and css required files?

For example, I can see that there's a css/base folder that contains selectmenu.css but I guess it's not the only css I should use and I can't find docs on what that file should be. Maybe core.css it's enough, but I don't know.

Idem for js: I now I can just include jquery-ui.js, but I'd like to use only selectmenu.js with dependencies (maybe core.js?) but they're not listed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**js:** core, widget, position, menu, selectmenu. But these you can already have from the builder page:

http://jqueryui.com/download/

**css:** selectmenu.css

If you want you can also add core.css and/or menu.css but as far as I can see now, they're not mandatory.